# my little bit of ajax over an element in a table breaks if table is large. how to fix?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have page with multiple tables being generated by php/mysql. One of the elements is a in/out button. I have it ajax'ed so that the button changes to the on or off image with each click without reloading the page.

And it worked like charm! Until it didn't. If one table or a combination of tables exceeds so many rows...it stops working. But still works on the rows above it. Why would that be?

Here's the table generation...this occurs in multiple php files.

```
<tbody>
<?php while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)):
$id = htmlentities($row['id']);
$status = htmlentities($row['status']);
include ("button.php");
?>
<tr>
        <td title="lname" width="100px">
            <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                <?php echo(htmlentities($row['last_name'])); ?>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="100px">
            <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                <?php echo(htmlentities($row['first_name'])); ?>
            </div>
        </td>    
        .
        .
        .
        <td>
        <div style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                <?php echo '<div><div id="r'.$id.'"><div id="test"><img class="rating" id="'.$status.$id.'" src="'.$color.'"><div style="display:none;">'.$status.'</div></div></div></div>';?>
        </div>
        </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $(document).on("click", ".rating", function(){
                var status = $(this).attr("id").substr(0,1);
                var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(1);
                var data = "id="+id+"&status="+status;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "rate.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(e){
                    $("#r"+id).html(e);
                }

            })
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here's the rate.php referenced in the code above:

```
<?php
include ("db.php");
$id = $_POST["id"];
$newstatus = $_POST["status"];

if($newstatus == 0){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE id='$id'");
}
else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE id='$id'");
}
include("button.php"); //FILE WITH THE LIKE & DISLIKE BUTTONS AND THE NUMBER OF LIKES & DISLIKES

$list = '<div id="test"><img class="rating" id="'.$q[0].$id.'" src="'.$color.'"><div style="display:none;">'.$q[0].'</div>';

echo $list;
?>
```

And the button.php file referenced above:

```
<?php 

$q = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
$q = mysql_fetch_array($q);

if($q[0]){
    $color = "green.png";
}
else{
    $color = "red.png";
}
?>
```

So yeah...if the mysql query for one table is too large, after a certain number of rows, the in/out buttons stop working. Or if I have multiple smaller tables, once it exceeds a certain total number of rows, same thing.

Help?

Comment: is the ajax request still being sent when it stops working? is the event happening? is the request failing? we need to know *why* it doesn't work. Just knowing that it doesn't work doesn't really help us help you.

Comment: It's doing something...but just once. On the rows that don't work, the image never changes to the opposite in/out image. But the first click does change the value in the mysql database. However, the second click no longer makes changes.

The working rows above those rows work right. The image changes on each mouse click, and the value changes in the mysql database on each mouse click...and it'll do so indefinitely.

Not sure if that helps you figure out what's going on!

Comment: Add an error callback to $.ajax and inspect the three parameters it receives.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Added the following to my ajax: "error: function(xhr, error){console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);},". But it shows nothing in the console on Chrome.

Comment: there's a third parameter to that, but if nothing is in console then it's not reaching the error callback anyway.

Comment: I viewed the Network tab in Chrome's developer tools. Clicking on the working or busted in/out buttons calls rate.php. Even the 'broken' buttons, status is 200 and OK. The broken one is supposedly POST'ing the correct data. And the response is correct as well.

Comment: in the success handler, what does `console.log($("[id=r"+id+"]").length)` give you?

Comment: Correction to my last comment: the broken ones are sending the correct id and status the first click. Response is correct. Clicking again sends the wrong status. Never changes for the site. BUT...it does change just ONCE in mysql database.

Comment: The line you asked me to add prints '2' to the console everytime I hit the broken buttons.

Comment: There's your problem. you have duplicate id's. :)

Comment: isn't that just printing the length of id?

Comment: Nope, it's counting the number of elements with the id.

Comment: But even the working ones are printing '2'. And 'id' is from r.$id...and $id is from the id column of the mysql query, where id is a auto_increment primary key...which i've verified are not repeating in the table.

Comment: could it possibly be repeating in a separate table? I don't see anything in your code that would cause the duplicates, i'm just goin on symptoms at this point.

Comment: kevin, yes! it was repeating in separate tables! so i changed a portion of my code...so now, the first time a entry appears, the id is "r.$id"..and the second time a entry appears in a table the id is "l.$id". your success code now prints '1' for everything. BUT...the symptoms are identical. no change. :(

Comment: well, at least we ruled that out.

Comment: Nope...you were right, Kevin! It was just the id's! I forgot to change some corresponding code in another file. It's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging in comments, it was realized that duplicate id's were being used. ID's must be unique within a single page, otherwise unexpected results may occur (such as the problem described in the question).

To test for duplicate id's, use the attribute equals selector.

```
console.log($("[id=" + theidtotest + "]").length)
```

if you ever get more than 1 elements from that line, you're doing something wrong.